# C++ multiple conversion operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I defined a class as below with two member variables and two conversion operators (operator float and operator chrono::microseconds). But the code below only works if I comment out the float operator. Otherwise, it throws an error (cannot convert type). I can't figure out why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class Peak {
public:
  Peak (std::chrono::microseconds t, float magnitude)
  : t_(t),
    magnitude_(magnitude)
  {
  };

  std::chrono::microseconds get_t() { return t_; }
  //have to comment this out or I get an error
  operator float() { return magnitude_; }
  operator std::chrono::microseconds() {
      return t_;
  }
private:
  std::chrono::microseconds t_{2us};
  float magnitude_;
};

int main()
{
  Peak a{3us, 100};
  std::cout
    << "t is "
    << static_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(a).count();
}
```

Comment: can't reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/AjCfKL please provide a [mre]

Comment: I can see the error here: cpp.sh/9c3cb

Comment: It seems to be related to gcc. In compiler explorer if I choose gcc 7.3 I see the error but 7.4 does not show error

Comment: Not an answer at all or dismissal as I think question is intersting but this is a really poor design and not how operators should be used. With two independent variables you should have a distinct getter for each.  Operators should all act as one would generally expect.  A cast operation of a tuple to yield a scalar value of any kind here is non-sensible.  One would expect that the casting is doing a conversation of the same value into a different type but you are simply returning two unrelated values.  I would say you are abusing operator(); nonetheless interesting question and find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a compiler bug in GCC 7.3 and older. A workaround seems to be building using the `-std=c++17` flag. Alternatively, making the `float` conversion operator `explicit` also fixes it:

```
explicit operator float() const { return magnitude_; }
```

(It's always a good idea to mark these `const`, by the way.)

Update:

Actually, just making these operators `const` seems to fix it already without the need to make the `float` one `explicit` nor to build with `-std=c++17`.

Comment: He isn't modifying his class internally so he should DEFINITELY mark them const.  why that fixes things is beyond me of course.
Explicit is certainly helpful here.  But what is he tries a char? It seems ambiguous.  I imagine c++ return type deduction plays a role